# Jquery Scrolling in a div affects the page

Tags: html, scroll

Hi all i have a page where, for style matters i must have a div with:

```
overflow:scroll
```

but the scrollbar into the div is pretty ugly, so i hid it, but now the user can't understand if he reached the bottom of the page.

How can I add a scroll bar to replace the browsers default scroll-bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of many javascript solutions:

see http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Basically it is unwise to attempt to style the browsers native scroll bar due to cross browser inconsistencies and a lack of w3c standards (different browsers may or may not support)

By using the javascript solution (that degrade back to the default scrollbar in the absence of javascript) you can apply any block level element and style it exactly how you want.